# Why 'this.userid' is assigning undefined value? does "this" pointing to the class or the object itself? timestamp_generate_function() works though

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

**Why 'this.userid' is assigning undefined value? does "this" pointing to the class or the object itself? timestamp_generate_function() works though.**

```
class price_update {


    constructor(api_key, url_endpoint, user_id, store_name) {
        this.api_key = api_key;
        this.url_endpoint = url_endpoint;
        this.userid = user_id;
        this.store_name = store_name;
    }

    #updatePriceQuantity_parameters = {
        Action: "UpdatePriceQuantity",
        Format: "json",
        Timestamp: this.#timestamp_generate_function(),
        UserID: this.userid,
        Version: "1.0"
    };
```

Comment: typo fixed. But still same problem.

Comment: `#updatePriceQuantity_parameters = ...` is executed before the `constructor()`, hence there's no `this.userid` yet.

Comment: i can access constructor variables from other methods of the class but not from the updatedPriceQuantity_Parameters..

Comment: `timestamp_generate_function()` is also "private". That's why you can access it in the private property `updatePriceQuantity_parameters`.

Comment: @Andreas wouldn't constructor initialize before others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**does "this" pointing to the class or the object itself?**
Yes.  `this` points to the object itself.

**Why 'this.userid' is assigning undefined value?**
You are attempting to set the value based on a property (`this.userid`) before you've ever defined it (either in the constructor or anywhere else).

Instead, you will want to do something like this in your constructor:

```js
class price_update {


    constructor(api_key, url_endpoint, user_id, store_name) {
        this.api_key = api_key;
        this.url_endpoint = url_endpoint;
        this.userid = user_id;
        this.store_name = store_name;
        this.#updatePriceQuantity_parameters.UserID = user_id;
    }

    #updatePriceQuantity_parameters = {
        Action: "UpdatePriceQuantity",
        Format: "json",
        Timestamp: this.#timestamp_generate_function(),
        UserID: '',
        Version: "1.0"
    };
```

Note that we're setting the value in the constructor while we're inside of the instance of the object itself.  You can do it like this, or in another method if you like.  Either way, you have to instantiate the object first before you and access/apply properties that you have set during construction.

Answer (score 0):

> does "this" pointing to the class or the object itself?

In this case, `this` refers to the object. No, not the JavaScript's object (`{}`) data type, but the instance of the `price_update` class when instantiated with `new price_update()`.

Oh, right, **you have a typo there** (`user_id1` instead of `user_id` in the constructor parameters). `user_id` was not defined there (even though the SO mods edited the question), hence undefined.

**Snippet of the original post:**

```
class price_update {


    constructor(api_key, url_endpoint, user_id1, store_name) {
        this.api_key = api_key;
        this.url_endpoint = url_endpoint;
        this.userid = user_id;
        this.store_name = store_name;
    }

    #updatePriceQuantity_parameters = {
        Action: "UpdatePriceQuantity",
        Format: "json",
        Timestamp: this.#timestamp_generate_function(),
        UserID: this.userid,
        Version: "1.0"
    };
```

Comment: _"Oh, right, you have a typo there..."_ - No, that typo is already fixed

Comment: typo fixed. But still same problem

Comment: Oh, I thought that someone else edited the question to remove the typo. However, mistakes like these often lead to `undefined` madness. The OP (original poster) should re-check whether the updated code works, especially if the code was first copy-pasted from an IDE.

Comment: @ReinhartPreviano typo fixed but problem exists.